# How is the ? operator different than including undefined in the type?

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between these?

```
type A = {a?: string}

type A = {a: string | undefined}

type A = {a?: string | undefined}
```

When would I use one over the other?

Related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight distinction between having an object with a property being set explicitly to `undefined`, and an object with that property not being there at all.

```js
type A = {a: string | undefined} // No "?", so this enforces that key "a" must be present!

let varA: A = { a: undefined } // OK
let varB: A = {} // Not OK, because key "a" is not present
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `?` means you can omit that value, but using `undefined` means you must provide either a string or undefined.

```
// Note: Tested with Typescript 3.8.3
type A = { a? : string }
type B = { b: string | undefined }

const objectA: A = {} // OK!
const objectB: B = {} // ERROR: property 'b' is missing on type B
```

In general, I think that using `?` is what you want most of the time, since you want the value to default to `undefined`. Very rarely have I ever come across a case where I want users to explicitly enter `undefined` as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the ? means that A may or may not exist, and A can be a string and undefined. Defining an undefined type doesn't mean it isn't there.

The undefined has to do with A's content, and ? sign ios related to its existence. You can use both together, but if you're sure that A will always be there, use just undefined.

Answer (score -1):

This TypeScript, it will cause an error in JavaScript.

The question mark means the property is optional, `| undefined` is pointless as all properties can have undefined assigned as it's value.

If you define the type

`type A = {a?: string, b: string}`

then you can define a variable without a

`let x: A = { b: 'some value' };`

`type A = {a: string | undefined}` offers nothing over `type A = {a: string}` as the a property still needs to be in the declaration and a string can already have undefined assigned to it.

`let x: A = {}` is an error as you didn't supply a and `let x: A = { a: undefined }` is allowed with `type A = {a: string}`

This make `| undefined` pointless as any property can have undefined assigned to it anyway.